# Separate y-values depending if the x-value is increasing or decreasing

Tags: matlab

I try to analyze my data using a mixture of python and matlab, but I am stuck and could not find any discussion that solves my problem.
My data consists of temperature and current measurements which are recorded at the same time but using two different devices. Afterwards these measurements are matched together using the time stamp of each measurement to get the "raw data plot". However, the current values differ at the same temperature depending if the sample was heated up or cooled down.
Now, I would like to separate the heating and cooling values of the current measurements, and calculate the mean and standard deviation for all currents at one temperature for cooling and heating, respectively.

What I do so far is first looking for all the values that are beloning to the same temperature, no matter if it's a cooling or heating cycle. That results in quite large standard deviation values.
The two figures show a simple example how my data looks like.

The first figure plots the temperature values against the number of data points and marks all values that belong to this temperature:

[image: The first figure]

The second figure shows the current data with the marked values that correspond to the temperature.

[image: The second figure]

The temperature is always kept constant for 180 s and then increased or decreased by 10°C. During the 180 s several current measurements are taking place, which results in several data point per temperature per cycle. The cycle is repeated itself several times (not shown here). To simplify the example here, I just used simple numbers instead of real temperature and current values. The repetition of the same number, indicates several measurements at one temperature. In reality the current values are not completely stable, but fluctuate around a certain value (which I also irgnoered here).

The code which does that looks like this:

Sample data:

```
Test_T = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1] ;
Test_I = [5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4] ;
```

Code:

```
Test_T_sel =Test_T;   
Test_I_sel = Test_I;

ll = 0;
ul = 2;

ID = Test_T_sel <ul & Test_T_sel >ll;

Test_x_avg = mean(Test_T_sel(ID));
Test_y_avg = mean(Test_I_sel(ID));

figure('Position', [100 100 700 500]);
plot(Test_T_sel);
hold on;
plot(find(ID), Test_T_sel(ID), '*r');
ylabel('Temperature [°C]')

figure('Position', [900 100 700 500]);
plot(Test_I_sel);
hold on;
plot(find(ID), Test_I_sel(ID), '.r');
ylabel('Current [µA]')
```

And `Test_T` contains 90 values increasing stepwise from 1 to 5 each 10 values, while `Test_I` contains the current values. As you can see for `Temperature = 1°C` the current values is either 5 or 4. Now I would like to get a vector that only contains the values of `T` and the corresponding value of current if `T` increases and a second vector for the current values were `T` decreases.

I thought using a if else comand, but I actually do not know how to implement this. Maybe something like this could work:

`if T2 == T1 and T2-T1 <= 0.2` "take corresponding I values" (this is true when the temperature is stable and only varies by 0.2°C)

`if T2-T1 > 0.2` "ignore I values until" `T2 == T1` again `and T2-T1 <= 0.2` (this would either be a stronger variation at one temperature or indicate a temperature change and waits until T is constant again)

But now, I still need to distinguish if the temperature is generally increasing or decreasing after 5 measurements.

`if T2 > T1`, T is increasing (`Test_T_heat`) and the correspnding I values should be written in a vector `Test_I_heat`

`if T2 < T1`, T is decreasing (`Test_T_cool`) and the corresponding I values should be written in a vector `Test_I_cool`

For the example given above this should look like this at the end:

```
Test_T_heat: [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5];
Test_I_heat: [5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9];


Test_T_cool: [4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1] ;
Test_I_cool: [7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4] ;
```

How has the "code" to be changed that I get such vectors?

Comment: You need to explain what the temperature cycle was. Was it like: "temperature increase ... temperature stays stable ... temperature decrease", or more like "temperature always oscillating between 2 values"... Also some sample values would be helpful.

Comment: The temperature is kept constant for 3 min, and then is either increased or decreased by 10°C and kept again constant at the new temperature. This is done for a certrain range (-20°C to 60°C in reality) for several times. However, I tried to simplify that and used the following values. Test_T: 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1 and Test_I: 5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,4

Comment: I added your code in the main question. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58608340/edit) your question if you want to add information (instead of putting it in comment). Question: Why are your values repeated 5 times each ? Is it meant to be like that or is it just the sample data you chose ?